# Could a helicopter fly on Mars?

Tags: mars, aerodynamics, technology, helicopter

Helicopter drones are awesome fun down here on Earth, but what if... we took one to Mars? This sounds like a good question for [Randall Munroe](https://what-if.xkcd.com/54/). But I read about a proposal to send a helicopter drone (MHS) to Mars with [Mars 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_2020).

[image: Mars Heli-drone]

Martian atmosphere's density is a fraction of a percent of Earth's (average [0.6%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars#Atmosphere) ASL). My off the cuff calculations say that such a drone would have to be 200 times more powerful than its Earth-bound cousins.

Is this a realistic proposal?

Comment: How did you got to that number ?
Two things:
We can increase lift by increasing the rotors size
Gravity is significantly weaker

Comment: You don't have to have 200 times more power. You have to spin much faster and have bigger rotor blades to generate lift, but you don't need to add much more energy into the process.

Comment: I recommend [xkcd what-if: Interplanetary Cessna](https://what-if.xkcd.com/30/) for a crash course (no pun intended). See also NASA's [Preliminary Research Aerodynamic Design to Land on Mars, or Prandtl-m](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/armstrong/features/mars_airplane.html) (yes, that's what it really is called).

Comment: They have done tests proving that a small drone-like helicopter (about 1 meter across) would be able to take off and fly in Mars' thin atmosphere.

Comment: Increasing rotor size only works up to a point. Increase the diameter enough, and your rotor tips will go supersonic, which doesn't help lift.

Comment: @Hobbes: never mind increase thickness towards the middle or it rips itself apart. But you can relatively harmlessly increase the blade width somewhat.

Comment: By bigger I meant a wider shape, not necessarily longer @Hobbes. Length is a problem for stowage anyway.

Comment: @aCVn Love NASA's acronyms :)

Comment: It has now been proven that a helicopter can fly on Mars.  Finding reliable cites is left as an exercise for the interested student.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Gravity is about a third of Earth's and competitive aerobation helicopter models have a truly excessive power surplus. Just look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PptMrBFAO-A).

There won't be any manned helicopter flight. The helicopter power scales poorly with size - there's a reason we have no VTOL Jumbo Jets. But the same up-scaling issue is our friend when down-scaling. A [6kg helicopter can lift 30kg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-PigXQWChs) of payload, so we have equivalent of TWR=6 on Earth.

Drag and lift are both identically (quadratically) proportional to airspeed, so the same loss of lift causes loss of the primary limiting force of the helicopter - air drag on the blades. What's left is mechanical losses (friction of bearings), and mechanical durability of the construction, but these can be built with much surplus - plus larger rotor blades will offset need for extreme RPM.

Of course other things must be taken into account. These flights will be more like "hops" - a short segment of flight followed by a looong recharging period. And the drone will need to be small - and that means not much scientific equipment. Unfortunately, that also means it won't be fully autonomous as there simply won't be enough room to fit a good radio and antenna to reach Earth, or even the satellites. But it could definitely serve as a "recon vehicle" for a large rover, fetching small samples, testing firmness of ground surface for driving over, and planning the best route.

2021.03.16 edit:

[Ingenuity has performed its first flight.](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/25828/first-video-of-nasas-ingenuity-mars-helicopter-in-flight/). Most of data in my post predicted Ingenuity's parameters correctly. 2,500 rpm at 60cm rotor radius gives 157m/s top linear speed of the rotor tips, vs 267m/s speed of sound in carbon dioxide (and 90m/s in aerobation RC helicopters), so they remained subsonic. It's lightweight - 1.8kg, comparable to heavier aerobatic models. It uses the rover as a retransmitter to contact the satellites and Earth. The rotor blades are both wider and longer than in aerobation RC helicopters to compensate for the thin atmosphere, but the motor is comparable to mid-shelf models regarding power output. The helicopter is capable of a 30s flight and requires a day to recharge the batteries.

2021-09-05 edit:

As the first phase - technology demonstration of feasibility of powered flight on Mars has ended, [Ingenuity performs reconnaissance work](https://twitter.com/NASA/status/1423012693439651840?s=20) helping Curiosity pick interesting targets.
[image]

Comment: You need to address the factor of 100 atmospheric density difference in your answer, which is the question that was asked. To get the same lift, you need the airfoils to move 10 times as fast.

Comment: @Mark: which I can, due to reduced air drag - same torque caused by air resistance. Regardless of speed and pressure, torque to lift ratio remains the same. (minus other resistances which are taken care of by the power surplus, and plus reduced lift requirements thanks to low gravity.) Air drag doesn't rise; other frictions increase by factor of ~60 (x200 density /3 gravity) but I believe they account for less than 10% of original losses, so the 6x power surplus is enough to overcome them.

Comment: No, the air drag does rise, where the dimensionless drag coefficient goes up dramatically as you approach Mach 1, starting as low as Mach 0.6. So it doesn't scale to low density as nicely as you claim.

Comment: @MarkAdler: What order of increase can we expect, with the blades designed for the purpose?

Comment: It depends greatly on the details of the wing, and the other constraints you have on it. Could be a factor of 3, could be a factor of 10. See https://mhmaberry.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/2.jpg for an example. This sudden increase in drag is why there is a "sound barrier", since the drag drops off again above Mach 1. See this for the generic picture of the situation: http://history.nasa.gov/SP-367/f86.htm

Comment: @MarkAdler: Well, they currently can a) increase the speed about 2-2.5x to just nudge the edge of the slope - model helicopter blades go about 90m/s, b) go with multi-bladed designs (quadcopter etc) c) put the blades on thin, very low friction bars and go full supersonic - 1 mach in CO2 is 267m/s, 77% of air, and the surplus torque should be enough to cross the 1 mach barrier.

Comment: Scaling works on paper if you're talking about gravity, but how will it affect maneuverability?

Comment: @duaneellen: The need for operation around the max of engine performance, due to lack of the 6x surplus of power, plus the poor atmospheric density will definitely adversely affect maneuverability. OTOH the maneuverability of aerobation helicopter models is simply insane - so even a massive drop will still leave the performance at *satisfactory* levels.

Comment: That would I call a real proof of an expert. Predictive power. (Check also the first version of the post from 2016).

Answer (score 36):

There's nothing like seeing it flying in a Mars-density chamber to answer your question:

[Crazy Engineering: Mars Helicopter](https://youtu.be/vpBsFzjyRO8?t=1m43s)

I have a really nice video of it in controlled flight in the chamber, but I can't find that one on the interwebs yet.

*Update two years later:*

Thanks SF for [this link to nice video](https://youtu.be/oOMQOqKRWjU?t=56s).

Answer (score 9):

You can calculate the hover power required out of ground effect by using the following formulas:

Given $m$, the mass of the helicopter, the required lift force is  $L = g_{Mars}\cdot m$

The required shaft power is:

$$P = \frac{\frac{L^{\frac{3}{2}}}{R} \cdot \sqrt{\frac {2} {\pi \cdot \rho} }}{FM}$$

where $R$ is rotor diameter and FM is the "figure of merit". For a small helicopter the FM is smaller than 0.66, say 0.55.

The density at low altitude on Mars is  0.0152 kg/m<sup>3</sup>

The gravitational acceleration $g_{Mars}$ is 3.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>.

**Example:**

- mass = 2 kg
- lift = 7.6 newton
- FM = 0.55
- rotor diameter = 1 meter
- density = 0.0152 kg/m<sup>3</sup>
- pi = 3.1416

The result is 264 watts.

The fact that the counter rotating rotors are coaxial does not significantly reduce the hover power. The effective diameter is nearly the same.
Note that, when the mass is reduced to 1 kg the required power would be only 87 watts!

In summary: power required is proportional to (lift to the $\frac{3}{2}$ power exponent), inversely proportional to rotor diameter and inversely proportional to the square root of the density.

When flying forward instead of hovering the required power goes down significantly for a well shaped streamlined fuselage.
In  1929 Glauert came up with an approximate formula (the solution of a quartic) which is still used today. A good reference text book is: B. W. McCormick: *Aerodynamics of V/STOL Flight*.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and do something about the [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text)

Answer (score 3):

I do not object to Mark's answer, but I am concerned with the rotor blades rotating so fast that they will be entirely within a supersonic flow. Maintaining helicopter blades within a subsonic flow is a limiting factor for helicopter speeds here on earth. How would the rotor's lift be affected if it were entirely behind a shockwave? On earth most subsonic wings placed in such conditions simply stall. Also because Mars' atmosphere is so cold, the local sound velocity should be quite low, hence a rotor for Mars better be designed to function within transonic and supersonic regimes. A good example of this problem: the U2 spy plane (granted not a helicopter) at its highest altitude it was at the combined limits of not flying fast enough to generate enough lift (in atmosphere), or flying too fast and going supersonic (low local sound velocity) which was not good for the type of plane it was.

Comment: This is called the "Coffin corner". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffin_corner_(aerodynamics) .

Comment: Wit the right airfoil, a rotor can work at supersonic speeds. The reason this isn't done on Earth is the huge amount of noise generated by supersonic propellers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ingenuity has proven this capability through its various test flights. This was actually the primary goal of the mission, as [NASA states](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/6-things-to-know-about-nasas-ingenuity-mars-helicopter/#:%7E:text=Ingenuity%20is%20intended%20to%20demonstrate,and%20human%20missions%20to%20Mars.).